# css/jquery - how to hide last row of floated elements if not even

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a quick and simple way (either in css or jquery) to hide the last row of floated elements if they are not even.

See JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cohhvfjn/

When you resize the html container, sometimes the last row of floated elements may have 3 items when the row above it has 4, same thing when it's resized down further so the last row has 1 item when the row above it has 2.

Basically I'm trying to remove/hide that last row only if the number of items in it doesn't match the row above.

Can someone help me out with this?

Here's the basic html included in the jsfiddle:

```
<style>
    .content {width:100%;}
    .content .block {float:left;width:20%}

    @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
        .content .block {width:25%}
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 500px) {
        .content .block {width:33.3%}
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 400px) {
        .content .block {width:50%}
    }
</style>
<div class="content">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this 'div block' getting created?

Comment: something you should do on the server side, not on the frontend/client side, imho.

Comment: @lxer I agree, but not everyone has access to the server side.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh - blocks represent records returned from a db, rendered via php

Comment: @lxer and divinecomedian - attempting to do this server side defeats the point of responsive design as browser width etc can't be determined, not to mention orientation changes on mobile devices would mess it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of `nth-child` and `nth-last-child()`.

When you want 4 items to a row you can target every 4th element starting at the 1st (so 1, 5, 9, ...) that is also the last child (meaning it's the only item in the last row), the 2nd to last child (there are only 2 items in the last row), or the 3rd to last child (there are only 3 items in the last row).

The same concept applies to rows of other lengths.  [This article by Heydon Pickering](http://www.heydonworks.com/article/tetris-the-power-of-css) is very helpful in this situation.

**Note:** I altered your media queries to make my demo more manageable and also used an `<ol>` to number items for clarification.

```html
<style>
    .content {width:100%;}
    .content .block {float:left;width:20%}

    @media all and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 600px) {
        /* 4 elements to a row */
        .content .block {width:25%}
      
        .content .block:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(1),
        .content .block:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(2),
        .content .block:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(2) ~ .block,
        .content .block:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(3),
        .content .block:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(3) ~ .block {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 500px) {
        /* 3 elements to a row */
        .content .block {width:33.3%}
      
        .content .block:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(1),
        .content .block:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2),
        .content .block:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2) ~ .block {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 400px) {
        /* 2 elements to a row */
        .content .block {width:50%}
      
        .content .block:nth-child(2n+1):last-child {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
<ol class="content">
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
    <li class="block">Text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Nice solution that does not need JavaScript! I should point out though that nth-child support is relatively recent: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child in particular if you need support for pre-IE8 this may not be a good solution.

Comment: One of these days we'll have nice things.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
function hideOdd() {
    var blocks = $(".block");
    blocks.show();

    var nr_per_row = Math.round($(".content").width() / blocks.width());

    var elements_to_hide = blocks.length % nr_per_row;

    for (var i = 0; i < elements_to_hide; ++i) {
        blocks.eq(blocks.length - i - 1).hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("resize", hideOdd);
    hideOdd();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cohhvfjn/1/

Comment: I wish I could pick two answers, via css is always the first goal however for legacy browser support I'll be using your solution. Thanks for your time on this :)